# Limit the number of results in a dropdown when pulling from a spreadsheet with multiple columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google web app that I am creating and have hit a snag.

In this app I use multiple dropdowns. These dropdowns are pulling data from a spreadsheet using the below code.

```
var userList = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var sourceList = ws.getRange(2,2,ws.getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
```

Now, the problem I am running into is that every single dropdown I use is as long as the longest column in the spreadsheet I am pulling the values from. For example. If column A has 4 values and column B has 12 then the dropdown that pulls from column A will have the four values plus an additional 8 blank values.

How can I change up this code to get the last row of the column I'm pulling values from and not the last row of the longest column? I know I can just put a number value in place of `ws.getRange("A2").getDataRegion().getLastRow()` but I'll be adding new options to the dropdown regularly and would prefer not to have to update the code each time.

Here is the function where this needs to happen

```
function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId)
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("List Source - External");

  var range = ws.getRange("A2");


    Logger.log(range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getA1Notation());
      var lastRowInColumnA = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
      var userList = ws.getRange(2,1,lastRowInColumnA-1,1).getValues();
      var sourceList = ws.getRange(2,2,lastRowInColumnA-1,1).getValues();

      //var userList = ws.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
      //var userList = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getRange("A2:A").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      //var sourceList = ws.getRange(2,2,ws.getRange("B2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      var brandList = ws.getRange(2,3,lastRowInColumnA-1,1).getValues();
      var brand2List = ws.getRange(2,3,ws.getRange("C2").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();

      var userListArray = userList.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
      var sourceListArray = sourceList.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
      var brandListArray = brandList.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
      var brand2ListArray = brand2List.map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');

      var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("builder");
      tmp.userList = userListArray;
      tmp.sourceList = sourceListArray;
      tmp.brandList = brandListArray;
      tmp.brand2List = brand2ListArray;


      return tmp.evaluate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This can be achieved with [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)

This method gives you the last not empty cell of an adjacent data range in the specified direction.

Sample:

```
  ...
  var range = ws.getRange("A2");
  Logger.log(range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getA1Notation());
  var lastRowInColumnA = range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var userList = ws.getRange(2,1,lastRowInColumnA-1,1).getValues();
  var sourceList = ws.getRange(2,2,lastRowInColumnA-1,1).getValues();
  ...
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample how you can find the last row of each column individually within a loop:

```
function doGet(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId)
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("List Source - External");  
  var range = ws.getRange("A2:D2");
  var valuesArray = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getLastColumn(); i++){
    var lastRowInColumn = range.getCell(1, i).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    var list = ws.getRange(2,i,lastRowInColumn-1,1).getValues();
    valuesArray.push(list);
  }

  var userListArray = valuesArray[0].map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var sourceListArray = valuesArray[1].map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var brandListArray = valuesArray[2].map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');
  var brand2ListArray = valuesArray[3].map(function(r){ return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>'; }).join('');

  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("builder");
  tmp.userList = userListArray;
  tmp.sourceList = sourceListArray;
  tmp.brandList = brandListArray;
  tmp.brand2List = brand2ListArray;

  return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: This works great but it looks like I would need to define a new range variable for each column since the current range variable is using "A2" right? Actually, I'd need to create individual variables for "lastRowInColumn" too.

Comment: It depends on how many dropdowns you have and on either they should all have the same length or individual lengths. If each dropdown should have a different length - in function of the length of the column from where the data is pulled, then indeed you need to get the last row in each column.

Comment: If you have many dropdowns, you can simplify this by using a loop. E.g. `for (var i = 1; i  <  ws.getLastColumn(), i++){ var range = ws.getRange(i,2);...}`. That is you, get the range notation dynamically for each column. See [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column).

Comment: Yep. Multiple columns of different lengths. So are you saying to simply replace `ws.getRange("A2")` with the loop?

Comment: Well, you'd need to to implement the retrievement of ranges and values in each column within the loop, but in order to prevent overwriting during each iteration you need to push the values into an array. What you want to do with this value array depends on the rest of your code.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'm not a coder by trade so this becomes a bit of a task figuring this out. Any good resources?

Comment: If you provide the rest of your code, I can give you a sample.

Comment: What would be the best way to provide that and how much do you need?  Just the function that is populating the dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, this should be enough.

Comment: What is the best way to share. It won't fit in the comments.

Comment: What is the difference between `brandList` and `brand2List`? Do you need them both?

Comment: Yes. They use the same source but used for different purposes within the app.

Comment: I updated my answer with a general of how to define each range within a loop. You might want to adapt it to your data. Hope this helps!

Comment: Works great! Had to make a change to the range variable to account for all of the columns and change the indexes for the second brand array which references the same column as the first brand array. Other then that..perfect. Thanks for the help!